# jquery ajax how to validate if a record exists in the db

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

using jquery ajax
i have a text field where a name is entered how can i have it where when a user enters a name ajax checks to see if the name already exists in the db and if it does a message is displayed that this name already exists and the form cannot be submitted until a name is entered that does not exist?

this would be the php

```
<?php
$name = $security->secure($_POST['name']) //security->secure() cleans the field
$query = $db->query("select name from table where name = '$name'");
if($db->num_rows($query) != 0) { "that record already exists"; }
//disable the form button until a name is entered that does not exist.
?>
```

Comment: i found a good explanation thnx: http://vimeo.com/4173282

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in Jquery you can use the method $.ajax, $.post , and even $.get to make an easy ajax call
example:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $.ajax({
     type: 'POST', /*the method u are using*/
     url: url, /* http://yourdomain.com/post.php */
     success: function(data){alert('Name exists')} /* What to do in case of success */
  });
});
```

I hope this was helpful enough to do the job for u .

Answer (score 1):

@sammen

you need to use jquery ajax

```
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/
```

send the user name to the backend , and execute your php and send a status to the UI.

on the success handler of ajax , you can call a  method or show a error that name is not valid

you can use jquery ajax for this