# how can I check if a record already in database before submitting form in ColdFusion applications

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-10

```
<cfquery datasource = "myDb" name = "compare">
    select *
    from users
    where cnic = #form.cnic#

</cfquery>
<cfif compare.cnic eq form.cnic>
        <p> *CNIC already Exists </p>
</cfif>
```

Comment: You can use `compare.recordcount GT 0` check as you are using `cnic` filter in query. Also user `<cfqueryparam value="#form.cnic#" cfsqltype="{typeofcolumn}">` instead of directly using form variable in query.

Comment: Write some javascript that uses AJAX to send the form value to a .cfc which does the database check.  You can run it when that form field loses focus.

Comment: an AJAX request would get the job done. Based on the response of the target page, you can either submit the form or fire an alert to the user.

Comment: Just to give you some examples of what others have said...I would do a combination of this (client side example):
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4382535/jquery-ajax-how-to-validate-if-a-record-exists-in-the-db
And this (for the CFC example)
https://www.raymondcamden.com/2011/08/31/Using-ColdFusion-and-Ajax-to-check-for-an-existing-database-record/
I would NOT use cfform/cfajaxproxy... because I don't like cfajax

Answer (score 0):

I think you're misstating the problem. It should be more like,

> "How can I show a form to add a record I know is not in the database?"

Please clarify if that is not the case.

Based on your code, I assume there's been a form submission from another page already. You're running a query to see if there is a record in the `users` table where `cnic = #form.cnic#`. If there was no previous form submission, then `form.cnic` wouldn't exist.

```
<cfquery datasource="myDb" name="compare">
    select *
    from users
    where 
        cnic = #form.cnic#
</cfquery>
```

So when this page loads, you've done your "check if a record is already in the database" with the query named `compare`. Now all you need to do is check if there are 0 records in the query.

```
<cfif compare.recordcount EQ 0>
    <!--- Display form here. ---->
</cfif>
```

If the query returns any records, then there is at least one record in the database, so no need to show the form or allow it to be submitted.

Answer (score 0):

You can use bellow code in Jquery ajax calling

```
<cfquery datasource = "myDb" name = "compare">
    select *
    from users
    where cnic = #form.cnic#

</cfquery>

<cfif compare.recordcount GT 0>
        <p> *CNIC already Exists </p>
</cfif>
```

Answer (score -3):

Depending on your database, too, there are other options.  MySQL has some features for INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)

In MSSQL you can do:
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM [users] u WITH (NOLOCK) WHERE cnic = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="CF_SQL_VARCHAR" value="#form.cnic#")
INSERT INTO [users].....

(My cfsqltype syntax might not be 100% correct, but always use .  Always.

Those might give you some other ways to handle your scenario.

Comment: Downvoted because the question asks how to check before the form is submitted.

Comment: Quite right.  <sniff>